# What does each stat do in Dungeon Siege 3?

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do certain item attributes in Dungeon Siege 3 mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24610/what-do-certain-item-attributes-in-dungeon-siege-3-mean)

Dungeon Siege 3 is big on the loot. It seems you can't walk two steps without tripping over some loot or another (all of it conveniently usable by your character), and there are an almost dizzying array of possible stats with which to find on them; What is lacking, is documentation about what each stat *does*.

For instance, what are the benefits of +Block vs. +Warding ? What does Chaos: Fire do, and how is it different from Chaos: Lightning?

Comment: Argument for reopening: The linked question asks about several specific attributes, while this question asks about *all* of them.

Comment: I would "merge" the questions and ask the other questioner if their question can be expanded to include all of them.

Comment: Opened a [meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/appeal-thoughts-on-dungeon-siege-item-attribute-questions) for you. See what you think ♪